# Ajax show response from php file after file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a html form to upload a file (I use php to do the upload). I want to show the result from the upload using ajax (I'm new to it, so I may miss something really simple), however, my code currently does not do that. I read a lot and tried many things, but in vain, so finally I decided to ask for help.

HTML & AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function( $ ) {
    $('form').ajaxForm({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Upload.php",
        data: $('#upload').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 15000,
        success: function( data ) { 
                    alert( data );
        }
    }); 
})( jQuery );
</script>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
        <h2>File to upload</h2>
        <input name="userfile" type="file" class='file'/>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
```

PHP

```
try
{
    if ( $_POST["send"] )
    {
        if ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) )
        {
            require_once "FileUploader.php";
            $fileUploader   = new FileUploader();

            if ( $fileUploader->moveFile() )
            {
                echo "Success";
            }
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
catch( \Exception $e )
{
    echo "\n" . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

Currently, alert( data ); results in the message NULL. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: maybe just because of `dataType: "json",` change it with `dataType: "html",`

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: You cannot upload a file like that, you need a `FormData` object to send it.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, I'm running on web-server,yes, I have added jquery(the alert is produced, it is just empty), there are no errors in the console

Comment: Note that if the conditions of your first 2 `if` statements are not met, the script will output nothing. Which is the result you are getting...

Comment: @jeroen,I upload the file using php, this part works, I want to use ajax to take the result after the upload - whether successful, or not. Maybe there is a better way to do it

Comment: Open the network tab in the browser's developer tools (F12) and watch the request/response.

Comment: You seem to be mixing standard jQuery ajax syntax with a form upload plugin so I have no idea what is happening. But if you really expect json back, you should make sure that your php script outputs valid json. Now you are outputting either text or nothing and both are not valid json.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, in the developer's tools, I do make a request to my PHP file, but there is only response header. Maybe I should not expect echo to be treated by ajax as a response

Comment: Echo is the only response you can get from PHP for an AJAX request. AJAX expects a string to be returned and that can only come from an echo. Change `dataType: "json",` to `dataType: "html"`, since all you're returning is text.

Comment: @devpro yes I had a wrong data type, I changed to html, you were right!! Thank you!

Comment: @Dimentica: glad to help u :)

Comment: @jeroen, you are also right, I did not meet the first 2 if statements, so I will have to work on that to get the right response, but it works now, thank you!

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I did not know Ajax expects a string, this is much help too!

Comment: The string could be one of several types: JSON, HTML, XML, text, script and JSONP [Choose wisely.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) read the dataType section. @devpro showed you the correction right out of the gate this morning.

Comment: @Dimentica main problem is using serialize() , that file input is not in it. you have to create your own formData to pass file throw AJAX

Answer (score 1):

AS I mentioned in comment, serialize() can not pass FILE, and you could check this with a simple `var_dump($_POST);` in your upload.php. you can pass your file in an instance of FormData() like below code

another problem is in your upload.php that uses FileUploader.php and I don't know what kind of code it has, but I try to fix your JQuery AJAX code with a sample of upload.php for you

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
          var form_data = new FormData(this);                  
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            data: {userfile:JSON.stringify(form_data)},
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 15000,
            success: function( data ) { 
                        console.log( data );
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
        <h2>File to upload</h2>
        <input name="userfile" type="file" class='file'/>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

your upload.php with some optimizations

```
try
{
    if ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) && $_POST["userfile"] )
        {
            require_once "FileUploader.php";
            $fileUploader   = new FileUploader();

            if ( $fileUploader->moveFile() )
            {
                echo "Success";
            }
            echo "Error";
        }
}
catch( \Exception $e )
{
    echo "\n" . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but,as I wrote in the above comments, it is now working with changing datatype to html. The upload itself is done through the FileUpload.php file, not the ajax code. Thanks for the corrections on my code, I really do need to work on it.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstood, changing datatype to html or text was a minor issue, I mentioned that you need FormData to send file throw post variable of ajax.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to set the Path where you post your File!

Comment: No, the file is successfully uploaded, the php works. Ajax does not get the result after the php has completed. If this was the problem, I would have said I cannot upload the file